# To find the number of times the function takes the same value in the given interval.

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, graphing-functions, problem-solving, maxima-minima

The number of times the function $$f(x)=|\min(\sin x,\cos x)|$$
takes the value $0.8$ between $\frac{20 \pi}{3}$ and $\frac{43 \pi}{6}$ is :

$A)2,\quad$  $B) \text{more than}\, 2,\quad$  $C)0, \quad $ $D)1$

I can only translate the interval into $[\frac{4 \pi}{6},\frac{7 \pi}{6}]$ but here what should I check to get the given answer?

**note** this is a past competition problem so use of any graphing calculator is not allowed. Only high school methods are acceptable. Thank you!

Comment: $~2 \times (0.8)^2 > 1.$

Comment: It does not ever achieve it. Assume that either $\cos(x)$ or $\sin(x)$ is equal to $0.8$ for some number $x$ in the given interval. Then by Pythagoras, the other length must have a magnitude of $\sqrt{1-0.8^2}=0.6\lt 0.8$. So $0.8$ cannot ever be the minimum.

Comment: In your mentioned interval, sine is positive upto $π$ and then is negative. However cosine is negative for the entire interval. From this we can conclude that the minimum will always be a negative number in this range, so the function never attains a value of 0.8